# What is the currently working and correct way to set up an Azure Application that allows MSA signin?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, adal, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-account

Scenario:
(Azure-hosted) Web App. Users should be able to sign in to my app using a Microsoft Account (i.e. @live.com, @hotmail.com, etc accounts) that has one or more Azure subscriptions. The application would then allow them to view and manage their Azure resources in specific ways through my app.

**Points of confusion/frustration:**

1. ADAL vs MSAL for authentication
2. Azure AD vs Azure AD B2C for the tenant hosting the application
3. Where do you register the tenant app? In the AD B2C under "App Registrations"? In a regular AD under "App Registrations (Preview)"? On the App Registration Portal (i.e. apps.dev.microsoft.com)?
4. Which of the above client ID & secret do you use in the web app (in the .config file)?

The documentation for none of these seem to cover the scenario end-to-end and most of it is completely out of sync with other developments.

I am hoping here to get some point of guidance from other developers that have actually gone through this journey themselves (rather than folks that just read the documentation). In specific, I am hoping to get answers from the **Azure CXP** team that monitors these questions and provides official & supported answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario requires access to Azure APIs, thus you have to make the logins against "regular" AAD, not B2C.
You can't make your logins against MSA accounts directly as they must be members of an AAD to have access to subscriptions.

You can use either ADAL or MSAL to handle the authentication.
Note you must use v2.0 endpoint for MSAL and the "v1" endpoint for ADAL.
See limitations of the v2 endpoint here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison.

You register it under Azure portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations.
You can also use the preview version if you want.

You will need the application id (= client id) + a key (secret) from the app registration.

Comment: That is how my "devbox" POC currently works. BUT, doing so does not let me let people other than me (who are not registered as users in my Azure AD) to login -- which is counter-productive to the app's purpose and eventual scope. Think of an application like Cloudyn's Cost Management.

Comment: An app like you are describing is a multi-tenant app. You register it in the same place, but mark it as multi-tenanted. Then you use the "common" (v1) or the "organizations" (v2) authority to allow a user from any AAD tenant to log in.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing now. BUT, if you try to login to the app (exactly configured in the way you described above), you will see the AADSTS50020 error. To workaround that, I would need to add your MSA to my Azure AD as a user account -- send you an Guest User invite and etc. That is not what I need.

Comment: It sounds like a user is trying to login with a pure MS account, which is not in an AAD. You can't access Azure APIs unless the user is an AAD.

Comment: The user is in AAD. Just not in *my* AAD. Like -- you have your Azure Subscription, so you are in the Azure AD, but under your Tenant. At the time you login to my app, you will receive the AADSTS50020 stating that you are not in *my* AAD Tenant.

Comment: Are you using the common/organizations endpoint? If you are using v2, you must use organizations.

Comment: I didn't get that last one. Could you provide more details? Or point me to relevant doc? I am using the OpenIdConnect from ADAL .net sdk to auth. I am not manually pointing it to any URL

Comment: When you redirect to login, look at the URL. If it says `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/....` then you are configured correctly. Since you are using ADAL, you need to be using the v1 endpoint, so the URL should not contain v2.0 either. This is configured as the "authority" in the app usually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189460/discussion-between-sujay-sarma-and-juunas).

Comment: I am marking this as the answer after quite a few days of experimentation with different combinations of these registrations and configuration!